# Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise automatically adds COMPLUS_ForceENC environment variable while debugging/running using IIS Express

Tags: environment-variables, web-config, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 version 16.3.10. Whenever I run/debug my web project using IIS Express, it adds **COMPLUS_ForceENC environment variable** as shown below:

```xml
<environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
```

Here is the screen print,

[image]

Every time I need to undo this change before committing my changes to source control. Please can anyone assist me on how to avoid this change?

Comment: This doesn't seem worthy of a full answer as I still don't know why it happens, but I found upgrading to Visual Studio 16.8.3 fixed it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time, I got response from Visual Studio developer community.

> The web.config only gets updated if you have the following section present in the web.config. You can remove the following from the web.config and running the application will not update the existing web.config. if you are using IISExpress, You can alternatively remove the full web.config from the project. web.config is not required in the project for running in IISExpress.

```xml
<handlers>
  <remove name="aspNetCore" />
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
  <environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44370" />
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
    <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
  </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

Here is the [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/867293/visual-studio-2019-enterprise-automatically-adds-c.html) for the same.

Comment: How is that an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this Enivronment Variable seems to be a workaround for enabling the "Edit and Continue" debugger feature.

[Source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7390#issuecomment-462962413)